# How can I globally set pgfmathsetlength?

Tags: tikz-pgf, lengths

How can I declare a length via `pgfmathsetlength` global?

The example results in
*20pt -- 5pt -- 20pt*
But I had expected:
*20pt -- 5pt -- 5pt*

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\parindent0pt
\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength\testl
\pgfmathsetlength\testl{20pt}
\begin{document}
\the\testl

{\global\pgfmathsetlength\testl{5pt}\the\testl}

\the\testl
\end{document}
```

I don't want to discuss possibilities with `\setlength` or `\deflength`.

Comment: What does your `.log` file say about using `\global`?

Comment: It's interesting that `\global` doesn't issue an error; this is because the token that actually it acts on is `\futurelet`; it definitely doesn't act on the setting of `\testtl`'s value, unfortunately.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `\global` like this  :

```
 {\pgfmathsetlength{\global\testl}{5pt}}\the\testl
```

Some remarks : Egreg notices this code is very similar to

`\setlength{\global\testl}{5pt}`

It may be interesting to know what the macro  `pgfmathsetlength` provides. In the file `pgfmathcalc.code.tes` we can read :

> ```
> % #1 = dimension register
> % #2 = expression
> %
> % Description:
> %
> % These functions work similar to \setlength and \addtolength. Only,
> % they allow #2 to contain an expression, which is evaluated before
> % assignment. Furthermore, the font is setup before the assignment is
> % done, so that dimensions like 1em are evaluated correctly.
> %
> % If #2 starts with "+", then a simple assignment is done (but the
> % font is still setup). This is orders of magnitude faster than a
> % parsed assignment.
> ```

Another possibility to declare a length  global is to redefine `pgfmathsetlength` but it's bad or to use a new macro :`globalpgfmathsetlength` based on `pgfmathsetlength`. We need to add `\global` in two lines but simplest is my first answer.

```
 \makeatletter
 \def\globalpgfmathsetlength#1#2{%
    \expandafter\pgfmath@onquick#2\pgfmath@%
    {%
        % Ok, quick version:
        \begingroup%
            \pgfmath@selectfont%
            \pgfmath@x#2\unskip%
            \pgfmath@returnone\pgfmath@x%
        \endgroup%
        \global#1\pgfmathresult pt\relax% here add \global before #1
    }%
    {%
        \pgfmathparse{#2}%
        \global#1\pgfmathresult pt\relax% and here
    }%
    \ignorespaces%
}
```

Comment: Very similar to `\setlength{\global\testl}{5pt}` (which works). :)

Answer (score 8):

Use a scratch dimension

```
{\dimendef\temp=0
 \pgfmathsetlength\temp{5pt}\global\testl=\temp}
```

Note. I wouldn't use `\testl` in place of `\temp`, in order to avoid "save stack buildup".

Comment: Interesting. Why does save stack buildup occur if `\testl` is used instead of `\temp`. Shouldn't the local assignment not being discarded at the end of the group?

Comment: @MartinScharrer It will happen if `\testl` has already been used in the outer level.

Comment: Why isn't a previously local assignment in the outer level not be discarded from the save stack as soon a global assignment is made? Or is this technical not feasible?

Comment: @MartinScharrer It's clearly explained both in the TeXbook and in TeX by Topic. A local assignment makes TeX push the "outer value" in the save stack and there it will remain, since the global assignment made in the group will tell TeX not to go fetching that value again. Why the useless entry is not discarded must be asked to Knuth.