# Problems with passing values through nested levels

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfplots

Inspired by a comment to another question, I'm trying to generalise some code to draw coloured in rectangles upon the graph of a function.

The routine `\findmax`, given an x-value and a function, calculates the maximum function value on [x, x+1] and the output shows it works, even within a loop.

The other routine `\maxboxes`, given two interval boundaries, a and b, and a function, is meant to place coloured in boxes of maximum height upon the graph, each box one unit wide, over the interval [a, b].

I set `\xbridge` to half a unit so that without using `\findmax` it prints out midpoint boxes. This routine also works. But, if you uncomment the `\findmax` call you get an error that expects a number, which I've narrowed down to the use of the passed in function.

Those passed in function calls work in the other cases in this code, and this thing is driving me nuts.

Note: Both these functions are initial designs, restricted to unit wide boxes, in order to focus on the basic idea. I will worry later about varying box width, minimum and average boxes and so on.

Please don't suggest packages that already work because there are several questions doing that already. This is just an example that I'm cutting my teeth on.

I realise my title needs work, but I'm really not sure exactly how to express it at this point in the context of LaTeX, as it's not like a third generation programming language. In the output, the data columns on the left are the maximum values followed by the left hand side of the interval plus the horizontal margin to the max value.

**MWE Output**

[image: MWE Output]

**MWE Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=14mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\pgfplotsset{
    maxbox/.style={draw=red, fill=red!10},
    /pgf/declare function={F(\x)=((sqrt(3)*\x/2.5)^3-9*(sqrt(3)*\x/2.5);}
}
\newcounter{colstep}
\newlength{\xval}
\newlength{\xbridge}
\newlength{\currentval}
\newlength{\maxbar}

\newcommand{\findmax}[2]
{%#1=left side of interval #2=function to be evaluated
    \pgfmathsetlength{\maxbar}{#2(#1)}
    \setlength{\xbridge}{0pt}%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,100}
    {%
        \pgfmathsetlength{\currentval}{#2(#1+\i/100)}
        \ifdim\currentval>\maxbar
            \setlength{\global\maxbar}{\currentval}%
            \pgfmathsetlength{\global\xbridge}{\i/100}
        \fi
    }%
}

\newcommand{\maxboxes}[4]
{
    %#1,#2=left and right boundaries of interval
    %#3=style for drawing boxes
    %#4=function to be evaluated
    \setlength{\xbridge}{0.5pt}
    \pgfmathsetcounter{colstep}{#2-1}
    \foreach \i in {#1,...,\value{colstep}}
    {
%       \findmax{\i}%{#4}
        \setlength{\xval}{\i pt}
        \pgfmathsetlength{\xval}{\i+\xbridge}
        \addplot [domain=\i:\i+1,#3,const plot]
        {#4(\xval)}\closedcycle;
    }
}

\begin{document}
%
\foreach \k in {-4,...,3}
{
    \par \findmax{\k}{F}\the\maxbar\quad\k+\the\xbridge
}
%
\par\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},
    xtick={-4,-2,2,4},ytick={-10,-5,5,10},
    y=0.30cm, xmax=4.4,ymax=12,ymin=-12,xmin=-4.4,
    enlargelimits=true,
    axis lines=middle,
    clip=false,
    axis on top
    ]
\maxboxes{-4}{4}{maxbox}{F}
% Function graph
\addplot[smooth, thick,domain=-4:4]{F(\x)};
%
\end{axis}
%
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Out of topic comment: control words will eat the following white-spaces so `%` is no longer needed.

Comment: I don't fully understand what the code is supposed to do, but there are a couple of errors: You need to comment out the lines starting with `#3=style` and `#4=function`. You can't use `\i` as the loop counter in both `\findmax` and `\maxboxes`. And for some reason, the `\setlength{\global` in `\findmax` doesn't work: Using `\pgfmathsetlength{\global` instead works, though.

Comment: `\global` is an extremely important command in TeX. Don't use existing macro names, but prefix with some personal identifier.

Comment: @percusse: I don't think Geoff is trying to redefine that macro name. He's using the keyword as it is supposed to be used, to globally set a length (`\setlength{\global\maxbar}{\currentval}`)

Comment: @Jake I think `pgfmathsetlength` is not aware of that. Is it?

Comment: @percusse: [Apparently](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38961/how-can-i-globally-set-pgfmathsetlength) it is...

Comment: @Jake Come on really? I spent an extra page of `@` jungle just because of that... Waiter a bottle of wine please

Comment: @Jake I've rewritten the OP to better explain what the code does. Right after posting the OP, I tried changing the loop counter names and it made no difference. Keeping them the same works in jfbu's answer. Using `\global` is what made the output on the left work in the first place. I'm still officially confused about what exactly works where and why.

Comment: @Marienplatz Trailing `%` characters do no harm. I delayed finding out exactly where I needed them and while I'm developing I put them in just in case. Having now tested the finer details, the only ones needed are after the \setlength calls and the \foreach brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(this update to incorporate better practice and avoid both a local and a global assignment to the same variable so now `\setlength{\dimen@}{\currentval}\global\maxbar\dimen@`, well no, simply `\global\maxbar\currentval`, don't know why the former use of `\setlength` which its accompanying issues of the patch done by `tikz`. Both are `<glue>` variables, so no problem could arise from a `\currentval` being only a `<dimen>`.)

**Edit: (explanations as per OP's request)**

Let me point out straight ahead that I have not studied the `pgf` source code, nor do I have any practice generally speaking of `tikz`, so reliable explanations could only be provided if I invested the time to do first the two previous things.

But, from adding at suitable locations `\tracingmacros1` (not anywhere, else very humongously gigantic log is produced) I have gathered that inside a `tikzpicture` the macro `\setlength` is redefined:

```
\setlength #1#2->\begingroup \pgfutil@selectfont \pgf@setlengthorig #1{#2}\expa
ndafter \endgroup \expandafter #1\expandafter =\the #1\relax
```

and this is incompatible with a `\global` in `#1` as we end up with

```
\pgf@setlengthorig #1#2->#1#2\relax 
#1<-\global 
#2<-\maxbar 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.101 \maxboxes{-4}{4}{maxbox}{F}
```

If the new `\setlength` had added braces around the `#1`

```
\setlength #1#2->\begingroup \pgfutil@selectfont \pgf@setlengthorig {#1}{#2}\expa
ndafter \endgroup \expandafter #1\expandafter =\the #1\relax
```

this would still not work because `#1` being two tokens, the \expandafter would not work as expected, also the `\the #1` part shows clearly that `#1` can not be anything else but a dimen or skip variable.

On the other hand it seems that with `\pgfmathsetlength`  one is allowed the `\global`. Anyway it appears that one reason your `\findmax` worked in one context and not in another is this redefinition of `\setlength` done by the `tikzpicture` environment.

The second issue appears to be with the use in the original `\maxboxes` of `\i`. Just replace there all occurences of `\i` with `\k`, and it works. Or, one does `\expandafter\findmax\expandafter{\i}{#4}` in order for `\i` to be expanded first.

Notice that you used `\k` in your loop which worked: if you do the same  in `\maxboses` it works too. But this seems to mean that one needs to know the name of the variables used by a `\foreach` loop in a macro to be able to use this macro in another `\foreach` loop with no conflict, so the safest way is the `\expandafter` way which allows you to use a colleague's macro without having to check how the iterated variable therein is called.

Regarding the difficulties building up a tabular with `\foreach`, as I said I have no prior knowledge of the source code, but it appears that the expansion of a `\\` in a tabular inserts a `}` and things such as `{\begingroup}\endgroup` give the `ERROR: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.` which perhaps you got from your trial with `\foreach`. Indeed it is quite possible that `\foreach` encloses the iterated commands in `\begingroup ... \endgroup` hence one ends up in the `{\begingroup}\endgroup` situation, the `{` being at the beginning of the tabular cell and the `}` from the expansion of the `\\`.

Loops which work inside tabulars have to be created with these constraints in mind. Among possibilities, I am obviously tempted to make propaganda for using either the completely expandable `\xintApplyUnbraced` or the non completely expandable but tabular-aware `\xintFor` macro from my package `xint`:

```
\begin{tabular}{|rr@{}l|}
\hline\xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq {-4}{+3}} \do
   {\findmax{#1}{F}\the\maxbar&\quad #1+&\the\xbridge \\ }
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

or:

```
\def\OneRow #1{\findmax {#1}{F}\the\maxbar & \quad #1+ &\the\xbridge \\ }

\begin{tabular}{|rr@{}l|}
\hline
\xintApplyUnbraced \OneRow {\xintSeq {-4}{+3}}
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

> [image: tabular]

This made me realize though that the `\findmax` needed one more fix, as it forgot to do `\global` on the initial values of `\xbridge` and `\maxbar`. As `\xbridge` was in another tabular cell, the used value was wrong.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=14mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\pgfplotsset{
    maxbox/.style={draw=red, fill=red!10},
    /pgf/declare function={F(\x)=((sqrt(3)*\x/2.5)^3-9*(sqrt(3)*\x/2.5);}
}
\newcounter{colstep}
\newlength{\xval}
\newlength{\xbridge}
\newlength{\currentval}
\newlength{\maxbar}

\newcommand{\findmax}[2]
{%#1=left side of interval #2=function to be evaluated
    \pgfmathsetlength{\global\maxbar}{#2(#1)}%
    \global\xbridge 0pt \relax
    \foreach \i in {1,...,100}%
    {%
        \pgfmathsetlength{\currentval}{#2(#1+\i/100)}%
        \ifdim\currentval>\maxbar
            \global\maxbar\currentval
            \pgfmathsetlength{\global\xbridge}{\i/100}%
            % \global in \pgfmathsetlength is OK
        \fi%
    }%
}

\newcommand{\maxboxes}[4]
{%#1,#2=left and right boundaries of interval
    %#3=style for drawing boxes
    %#4=function to be evaluated
    \setlength{\xbridge}{0.5pt}
    \pgfmathsetcounter{colstep}{#2-1}
    \foreach \i in {#1,...,\value{colstep}}
    {
        \expandafter\findmax\expandafter{\i}{#4}%
        \setlength{\xval}{\i pt}
        \pgfmathsetlength{\xval}{\i+\xbridge}
        \addplot [domain=\i:\i+1,#3,const plot]
        {#4(\xval)}\closedcycle;
    }
}

\begin{document}
%
\foreach \k in {-4,...,3}
{
    \par \findmax{\k}{F}\the\maxbar\quad\k+\the\xbridge
}
%
\par\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},
    xtick={-4,-2,2,4},ytick={-10,-5,5,10},
    y=0.30cm, xmax=4.4,ymax=12,ymin=-12,xmin=-4.4,
    enlargelimits=true,
    axis lines=middle,
    clip=false,
    axis on top
    ]
\maxboxes{-4}{4}{maxbox}{F}
% Function graph
\addplot[smooth, thick,domain=-4:4]{F(\x)};
%
\end{axis}
%
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

[image: passing values]

Comment: Isn't there in package `foreach` a variant to `\foreach` which does not do its repeated action in a group? It is a bit of a trouble to have to do `\global`. In fact rather than using `\global` inside the loop, it would be preferable to use some other loop than `\foreach`, as here the incremented thing is a simple numeric quantity, no need for the intelligent `\foreach` parsing.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, an explanation as to why your solution works and what exactly was wrong with what I was doing would help me a lot. I still don't get why I could run `\findmax` inside a `\foreach` loop to get the left hand output successfully, but it broke when called inside `\maxboxes`. Cheers

Comment: As a bonus question, I was trying to run `\findmax` in a loop inside a `tabular` to better present the data from the output test but it didn't go well. If you do the `\findmax` calls one at a time inside a `tabular` they work fine, but not in a `\foreach`. Any idea why?

Comment: This has indeed turned out to be quite a few lessons for me. You don't mess around. Much appreciated - Cheers

Comment: @GeoffPointer glad it helped :) (me too, I learned things on this occasion)

Comment: Okay, my routines now work without all the expanding and global references using `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` instead. I suppose I should use all the expanding and global references if I'm intending to build these into some kind of package?

Comment: @jfbu Did you see [How to define macros in a foreach loop with effects between iterations and after the loop without using global?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69470)

Comment: @PaulGaborit thanks for the pointer, no I had not seen it. Will have a look (as I don't use `\foreach` I will surely learn from this about things I don't know).

Comment: @PaulGaborit I looked but my natural move would be to _not_ use a `\foreach` loop! The `\xintFor` loops do not create groups, so the issue does not arise for them.